# How to filter yaml values based on sub-key and collapse them

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, json-query

I am trying to filter a YAML config file and collapse them based on a key.

For an ansible playbook I use the following config

```
    virtual_hosts:

      - vname: example
        server_name: "www.example.com example.com"
        port: 443
        ssl:
          cert: "star_example"


      - name: example_star
        server_name: "*.example.com"
        port: 443
        ssl:
          cert: "star_example"


      - name: foo
        server_name: "www.foo.com foo.com"
        port: 443
        ssl:
          cert: "foo"
```

I have tied to use a template

```
    - name: Certs Template
      set_fact:
        vhost_certs: "{{ lookup('template', './cert.yml') | from_yaml }}"
```

With the following cert.yml

```
      {% if virtual_hosts is defined %}
      {% for host in virtual_hosts %}
      {% if host.ssl is defined %}

    - name: "{{host.ssl.cert}}"
      private: " ... PRIV KEY ...."
      public:  " ... PUB KEY  ...." 

      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```

The problem is that `vhost_certs` will contain `star_example` twice.
In reality cert.yml does a lookup to get the private and the public keys using an Ansible plugin, so I would want to look them up only once.

I guess a better method would be to parse the `virtual_hosts` create a new object where the main key would be the `ssl.cert` add all the `server_names` do an actual lookup of the `private` and `public` keys and then check that the certificate is valid for all of the items in the `server_name`

e.g.

```
  vhost_certs: 

    - name: star_example
      server_names:
        - "www.example.com"
        - "example.com"
        - "*.example.com"

    - name: foo
      server_names:
        - "www.foo.com"
        - "foo.com"
```

Is there a way in Ansible to do this?

Update:

I have managed to create the list:

```
{{ virtual_hosts | json_query('[?ssl.cert].{cert: ssl.cert, domains: server_name }') | list }}
```

This does provide a `list`

```
item: {
   "cert" : "star_example"
   "domains" "www.example.com example.com"  
}
item: {
   "cert" : "star_example"
   "domains" "*.example.com"    
}
item: {
   "cert" : "foo"
   "domains" "www.foo.com foo.com"  
}
```

I would just need somehow to collapse it
to

```
item: {
   "cert" : "star_example"
   "domains" 
      - "*.example.com" 
      - "www.example.com example.com"   
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried [`virtual_hosts | subelements("ssl.cert")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#subelements-filter)? (I made up that dot notation, so the fact that your grouping key isn't at the top level may cause `subelements` to be tricker)

Comment: I am running Ansible v2.5.1  currently, I will give it a try using 2.7